# How to fix error on the container registry when the the container fails to start?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a cloud function in firebase project that receives a location data from multiple android app. The function then request the distance between a device an the rest of the devices using axios library.
I have installed firebase cloud function and firebase cloud admin in my windows 11 that I am using to deploy my project cloud function. This is the index.js file for my cloud function.

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require("axios");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const Firestore = require("@google-cloud/firestore");
const getlocation = async (res, pos) => {
  const endLat = pos.latitude;
  const endLng = pos.longitude;
  const googleMapsApiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  try {
    const locationRef = db.collection("Drivers");
    const querySnapshot = await locationRef.get();
    const distanceData = [];
    for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
      const data = doc.data();
      const startLat = parseFloat(data.latitude);
      const startLng = parseFloat(data.longitude);
      distanceData.push({startLat, startLng});
      const directionsApiUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=${startLat}%2C${startLng}&destinations=${endLat}%2C${endLng}&key=${googleMapsApiKey}`;
      try {
        const distanceResponse = await axios.get(directionsApiUrl);
        if (distanceResponse.data.status === "OK") {
          res.status(200).json({
            response: "OK",
          });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({error: "Failed to fetch distance data"});
      }
    }
    res.status(200).json({
      response: distanceData,
    });
    doc.data());
    // res.status(200).json({locations});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({error: "Failed to get locations"});
  }
};
app.post("/api/location", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pos = [];
    const locationData = req.body;
    const latitude = locationData.latitude;
    const longitude = locationData.longitude;
    const userPhone = locationData.user_phone;
    const userAuthToken = locationData.user_auth_token;
    pos.push({latitude, longitude});
    if (userAuthToken === "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx") {
      const userRef = db.collection("users");
      const userSnapshot = await userRef
          .where("user_phone", "==", userPhone)
          .get();
      if (!userSnapshot.empty) {
        userSnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({
          latitude,
          longitude,
        });
        await getlocation(res, pos);
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "User not found",
        });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(401).json({
        error: "invalid Token!",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error: ", error.message);
    res.status(500).json({
      response: "failed",
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
});
exports.app = onRequest(app);
```

When I try to deploy the function using

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I get an error that is about the container registry.

> Could not create or update Cloud Run service app, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'app-00033-hal' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

and also

> Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually

and also bring up this error in the google console cloud run logs

> he user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

Which when I remove the axios library and stop requesting, the function deploys well but brings up the cleaning up build image error. I have try running my container image locally and it works fine. I have also tried deleting the image in my project google console inside the artifact registry but the error is stills showing. please help me with me with solution on how to fix this.

Comment: This doesn't looks like a complete Cloud Function implementation.  There is no entrypoint function or anything that tells Cloud Functions where to start executing in response to an event.  Please edit the question to provide a [complete minimal example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) that anyone can copy and run for themselves.

Comment: Ok, let me edit my question

Comment: You still don't have a properly defined function that can be deployed by the Firebase CLI.  You import `onRequest` but never use it.  You should start with the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to get something simple working and understand how the product works.

Comment: I have edited the code by adding the function that is uses onRequest and also runs the get_location function

Comment: If you are still getting those errors with the complete code, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Comment: Ok, thank you. let me reach out

Comment: How can I run the container locally if it is from firebase?